# How to stop the head and footer of the page from the movement in htlm&css

Tags: html, css

I make a very beginning e-commerce page with HTML and I dont want  the header and footer to move when I go up and down

I was making the head with position:fixed and excepted to make the header and footer unremoved

Comment: Try with both `position: -webkit-sticky;` and `position: sticky;`

Answer (score 1):

try to make it sticky

```
.header, .footer{ 
position:sticky;
 }
```